# Groovy in Jenkins pipeline - create a file with content

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using Jenkins' [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and my Jenkins file has a stage like this:

```
stage('sonarqube') {
    when { branch 'master' }
    steps {
        generateUnitTestsReport()
    }
}
```

I want to keep programmers' repos clean from scripts that create various reports, so my idea is to keep definitions of scripts in a shared library, and then, during step execution, create a file with the content.

For instance (file `generateUnitTestsReport.groovy` in shared library):

```
def call(){
    def SCRIPT_CONTENT = '''
#!/bin/bash

#SCRIPT CONTENT
'''
    sh '''echo''' +SCRIPT_CONTENT+ ''' > ut-report.sh'''
    sh 'chmod +x ./ut-report.sh'

}
```

but it doesn't work like this. I also tried Groovy's `new File`, but no luck there either. How could this be done (note that this is a Jenkins slave node)?

Comment: Looks like a typo, should be `def SCRIPT_CONTENT = '''`. Unrelated: I would coalesce the two `sh` statements, which is more efficient (each `sh` create a new shell session).

Comment: Yea, it was a typo. Fixed. Thanks for the tip